# Make backspace behave like backspace in emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm new to emacs text editor and the fact that the backspace doesnt behave like a backspace that I have come to expect from every other text editor I have ever used is driving me crazy. Emacs just eats the currently highlighted character when I press backspace.

Ex.:
With | as the cursor (so c is highlighted):
ab|c with backspace

I want to get:
a|c

What I get:
ab|

Is there any way to config for this behaviour and are there any downsides?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't configure this yourself. In the situation you
described you're supposed to get `a|c`. (at least that's what I get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found here:
http://introrse.com/jasonc/docs/emacs-ch.html

Basically always bind the backspace to a set command.